# How to Tune following T-SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my `sql` `query`

```
SELECT MIN(CompletedDate), MAX(CompletedDate) FROM dbo.FactTable
        WHERE IdColumn IN ('guid1','guid2','guid3', 'guid4')
        AND NameColumn1 IN (N'150 comma seperated names')
        AND NameColumn2 = ('name')
```

executing against fact table with only 1.4 million records in `Data Warehouse`. It is taking 9 seconds to complete on my local machine.  CompletedDate column is nullable with non clustered index and lots of nulls. I need to know whether it can be optimised further with less execution time.

[image]

Comment: I think you need a covering Index.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `IN ('guid1','guid2','guid3', 'guid4')` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Thanks, I have edited with correct comma seperated guids

Comment: @RedDevil. I am not very good in indexing. could you suggest what type of cover index would be helpful

Comment: What all Index are on the table FactTable

Comment: Basically - Key lookup is bad. You want to use an index that will include all the relevant columns.

Comment: SQL Server *shouldn't* struggle with 150 values in a `IN` (far from it) but you *might* be better off with a temporary table/table variable and a `JOIN` at that point anyway; if for nothing else but readability.

Comment: @RedDevil. One clustered index and 18 non clustered indexes on 18 columns. there are 40 columns in fact table

Comment: Include the column CompletedDate in your Index. for eg: If you have an Index like: Create Index IDX on TableName (col1,col2) Then Rewrite that as Create Index IDX on TableName (col1,col2) Include (CompletedDate). This way your key lookup will be removed

Comment: @Larnu. Basically this query is similar to what visualisation tool dev express  generates and i was suggested that large in clause is a performance hazard.

Comment: Having a large number of values in an `IN` clause *is* a performance hazard, yes, @3355307 , however, this tends to be when you have several 1,000 values, not a couple of hundred. [In (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql) *"Explicitly including an extremely large number of values (many thousands of values separated by commas) within the parentheses, in an IN clause can consume resources and return errors 8623 or 8632. To work around this problem, store the items in the IN list in a table, and use a SELECT subquery within an IN clause."*

Comment: @3355307 how many distinct values does `NameColumn1` have? The server may well decide there's no point in doing an index seek even if `NameColumn1` is the first column in an index, if that means it's going to match 50% of all rows. It will decide to just scan the table

Comment: @RedDevil. Thanks. I created covering index and query now takes < 1 second to complete

Comment: In addition, you can consider the filtered index because your filter is constant expressions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. NameColumn1 could have 600-700 different distinct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create covering Index for column CompletedDate on your table.

```
Create Index IDX on TableName (col1,col2) Then Rewrite that as

Create Index IDX on TableName (col1,col2) Include (CompletedDate).
```

This way your key lookup will be removed.

Comment: we have 40 columns for our fact table. end users will design dashboards with different combination of columns and dev express visualisation tool will generate different queries. would it be better to track all queries and consider covering index per query

Comment: You can add upto 16 columns in the covering Index.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. so if i add 15 more columns in the include part of index that i created, it  should also optimise other queries which contain those 15 columns

Answer (score 0):

I am going to recommend to use table variable to hold possible `NameColumn1` values :

```
DECLARE @Names TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @Names (NAME)
     SELECT spt.col
     FROM dbo.splitvalue(@name, ',') spt

SELECT . . .
FROM dbo.FactTable ft
WHERE IdColumn IN ('guid1','guid2','guid3', 'guid4') AND 
      NameColumn2 = 'name' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Names N WHERE N.NAME = ft.NameColumn1);
```